# Cant move a resource between regions in Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a resource in Azure, an app service in region Central US. I want to move it to North Central US , so i have tried clicking on the "move"  next to location in the overview of the app service. It gives an error that it cant be moved , only certain resources can be moved across regions .

How can i move the app service to a different location ?

Answer (score 0):

You just can't, see [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-move-across-regions):

> App Service resources are region-specific and can't be moved across regions. You must create a copy of your existing App Service resources in the target region, then move your content over to the new app. [..]
>
> To make copying your app easier, you can clone an individual App Service app into an App Service plan in another region, but it does have limitations, especially that it doesn't support Linux apps.

Comment: so cant do it then , need to re-create in the destination  from whats in the docs ?

Comment: Also , if im not mistaken by that doc , Function apps cant have a static ip address or utilize Vnet Integration if they are using a Mode of  "Consumption" ?

Comment: @Angela both you statements are correct. VNET support for Consumption plan is a highly requested feature but there is still no news regarding that. See [this issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/646)